# Prop being passed to component from App.js before it is set ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-functional-component

I am currently having issues with a functional component in react. What I am trying to do is generate a random array, and then pass it as a prop to another componenet. However, the other component receives the array before it has had numbers added to it. Here is my App.js code:

```
function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([])
  const [length, setLength] = useState(4)

  const generateValues = () => {
    var newValues = []
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      values.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 10) + 10))
    }
    setValues(newValues)
  }

  console.log('render')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mount')
    generateValues()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Array values={values}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is the Array component the values are being passed to:

```
const Array = ({values}) => {
    console.log(values)

    return (
        <div className="array">
            {values.map((value) => (<Bar value={value}/>))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to use useEffect to set the values of the array before the other component renders, however, this is not working and an empty array gets passed. Would anyone be able to help fix this?

Comment: Everything seems to be working correctly. The changes to the `values` array should cause your `Array` component to re-render

Comment: This is what I thought, however, the array remains empty. This is weird because I thought the state setters cause a re-render when they are invoked. Do you have any other ideas what could be going wrong? Basically it does re-render but the array reamins empty upon re-rendering

Comment: Inside generateValues function: `values.push(...)` should be `newValues.push(...)`

Comment: I just found my issues. In generateArray values hsould be newValues

Comment: Yeah I just saw that at the same time Sly_cardinal, thanks for the help